# Tkinter Canvas.itemconfigure not used correctly?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently trying to make a game of life using tkinter.
One issue though: the rectangles I create won't respond to the itemconfigure method called to change their fill color. Once the tk window opened, there seems to be no way to change their color... Here is the code used: (variable names are in french, my apologies)

```
from tkinter import *
from numpy import *

Res = (1000, 1000)
dim = (50, 50)
BordABord = False

F = Tk()
C = Canvas(F, height = Res[1], width = Res[0])

L = ndarray(dim, dtype = bool)
Grille = ndarray(dim)

lar = []
for i in range(2):
    lar.append(Res[i] // dim[i])

for i in range(dim[0]):
    x = i * lar[0]
    for j in range(dim[1]):
        y = j * lar[1]
        Grille[i, j] = C.create_rectangle(x, y, x + lar[0], y + lar[1], fill = 'white')
        L[i, j] = False


def rgbTraducteur(rgb):
    return "#%02x%02x%02x" % rgb

def process():
    global L
    global Grille
    global dim
    global C

    for i in range(dim[0]):
        for j in range(dim[1]):
            if L[i, j]:
                print('processssss')
            C.itemconfigure(Grille[i, j], fill = 'black')

def clic(event):
    print('clic')
    global L
    global Res
    global dim

    x = int(dim[0] * event.x / Res[0])
    y = int(dim[1] * event.y / Res[1])
    print(x, y)
    L[x, y] = not(L[x, y])
    process()

def pas(event = 0):
    global L
    global BordABord
    global dim

    N = L

    for i in range(dim[0]):
        for j in range(dim[1]):
            compte = 0
            for k in range(-1, 2):
                x = i + k
                if BordABord or x // dim[0] == 0:
                    x %= dim[0]
                    for l in range(-1, 2):
                        if l != 0 and k != 0:
                            y = j + l
                            if BordABord or y // dim[1] == 0:
                                y %= dim[1]
                                compte += L[x, y]
            if L[i, j]:
                N[i, j] = (compte - 2) // 2 == 0
            else:
                N[i, j] = compte == 3
    L = N
    process()
                            
            

F.bind('<Button-1>', clic)
F.bind('<Return>', pas)
C.pack()
F.mainloop()
```

it is, of course, not optimised at all, and all rectangles have been set to turn black whenever process() is called as a test.

Comment: `Grille` is being created as a float array by default - I suspect the problem is that `.itemconfigure()` doesn't know what to do with item specifications with a decimal point in them, it probably interprets them as tag names rater than item IDs.  Try adding `dtype=int` to the creation of that array.

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you verified that the statement with `itemconfigure` is being reached? Have you verified that `Grille[i,j]` is what you think it should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Canvas items are given an integer identifier. You must use the integer to refer to the item. A floating point number such as `1.0` does not refer to the item with an integer identifier of `1`.

The problem in your code is that `Grille` is an array of floating point numbers. When you do `Grille[i, j] = C.create_rectangle(...)`, `create_rectangle` will return an integer but it gets stored as floating point. Thus, your call to `itemconfigure` tries to change something with the floating point number `1.0` rather than the integer id of `1`. If you pass something that is not an integer to `itemconfigure` the canvas assumes it is a tag. Since no elements have the tag `1.0`, no elements are configured.

If you change the array to hold integers so that the numbers aren't converted, `itemconfigure` will work fine.

```
Grille = ndarray(dim, dtype=int)
```